# GWT Access grid element value

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a Grid using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid; :

```
Grid g = new Grid (5,5);
```

I have added several elements to the grid through a sql query:

```
            g.setWidget(i, 0, texto(i, temp.get(1)));
        g.setWidget(i, 1, desplegable(temp.get(2)));
        g.setWidget(i, 2, texto(i, temp.get(3)));
        g.setWidget(i, 3, texto(i, temp.get(4).replace("%%", "")));
        g.setWidget(i, 4, gu);
```

"texto" and "desplegable" are both methods i have created to customize both a Textbox and a ListBox; both have a click event through which they can have their initial value changed / modified.

"gu" its a Button that i have created above the code above. "gu" has a click event which what it pretends to do is to get the values of the cell elements contained within the grid.

The following its an example:

```
ItemId        ItemName
-----------------------
01             Peak       [gu]
02             Paper      [gu]
03             Pick       [gu]
```

Now, when i click "gu", depending on which "gu" i click, i want to retrieve both values (itemid and itemname) from the grid. I know how to differenciate between which "gu" was clicked, but i dont know how to access the elements aligned to that "gu" button.

---

But until now i havent found how to do this.

Can anyone throw me some light on this?.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying? but manage elements in list or just get element from grid run time by index and loop through the all elements those are in grid and get values of it on click of "gu" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a reference to the row index of each button using a map, e.g.:

```
Map<Button, Integer> buttonRowMap = new HashMap<Button, Integer>();
...
g.setWidget(i, 4, gu);   // Your existing line
buttonRowMap.put(gu, i); // Keep a reference to the row index
```

Then in your ClickHandler you can retrieve the row index and the widgets on the same row:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
    Integer rowIndex = buttonRowMap.get(button);
    TextBox tb = (TextBox) g.getWiget(rowIndex, 2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi David Levesque, Thank you for the solution. I have tried it, and its exactly what i was looking for. Taking your answer for the accepted one. Cheers! :)